# MikTex+LyX .dll error

Tags: lyx, miktex, texworks

It all started when I tried to include a new package for MikTex to be used together with LyX.

Due to errors in LyX's Reconfigure command (which I needed to use in order for LyX to recognize the package), LyX stopped exporting .tex files.

So, I decided I'd reinstall it. My version was outdated, so as per instructions on the LyX website I downloaded the latest version (2.1.4), which comes with together with MikTex in a bundle (which I already had).

After installing everything, LyX works fine, however pdflatex files generated by LyX won't open in Texworks. I receive the following message (in a free translation from my computer's language):

> ```
> miktex-texworks.exe-system error: Your program cannot be initialized because QtScript4.dll in your computer. Try to reinstall it to solve the problem
> ```

I downloaded this .dll and put it into the bin folder of miktex, and now I get the same error but with different .dlls (also 2 errors instead of 1)

> ```
> miktex-texworks.exe-system error: Your program cannot be initialized because QtScriptTools4.dll is missing in your computer. Try to reinstall it to solve the problem
> miktex-texworks.exe-system error: Your program cannot be initialized because QtXml4.dll is missing in your computer. Try to reinstall it to solve the problem
> ```

Looking at my /bin folder for MikTex I noticed I have all these .dlls but with a '5' on them instead of '4' (Qt5ScriptTools.dll is there for example). So is LyX using an outdated version of those .dlls to generate tex files, which Texworks no longer supports, is that it? I'm using MikTex 2.9.4248 and 64-bit Windows 10. Prior to the bundle I had MikTex version 2.9.5105 (I tried to update it but got permission denied, after refreshing FNDB and whatnot).

So much for a simple package :/...

Comment: It sounds more the other way round: you have the newer dll (version 5), but an older texworks. Perhaps your texworks-link points to some older miktex. Regarding updating: Make sure to close everything miktex related before running the update manager (I probably wouldn't use the bundle but install miktex and lyx independantly.)